# Python and CodeEval: Why isn't my solution to this Multiplication Table challenge not correct?

Tags: python, formatting, multiplication

So I've been digging into some of the challenges at CodeEval during the last couple of days. One of them asks you to print a pretty-looking multiplication table going up to 12*12. While on my computer this solution works properly, the site does not accept it.

Can somebody help me out?

```
for i in range(1,13):
    for j in range(1,13):
       if j==1:
        print i*j,
       elif i>=10 and j==2:
        print '{0:3}'.format(i*j),
       else:
        print '{0:4}'.format(i*j),
    print
```

Here's a description of the challenge:

> Print out the table in a matrix like fashion, each number formatted to a width of 4 (The numbers are right-aligned and strip out leading/trailing spaces on each line).

Comment: Is there supposed to be an empty line at the end, or no? And are you sure each line does not end with a space?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there aren't any trailing white spaces. The problem is, CodeEval doesn't give any clue as to what the problem would be. I'm really confused :\

Comment: Is it correct, or not? I can't tell from your title...

Comment: The problem was that though it did seem correct on my local machine, CodeEval said otherwise. I've now fixed the problem. See zmo's answer, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Print out the table in a matrix like fashion, each number formatted to a width of 4
>   (The numbers are right-aligned and strip out leading/trailing spaces on each line).

I think that following code may pass, according to the given rules. But it's only a guess
as I'm not playing on codeeval.

```
# python3 code, use from __future__ import print_function if you're using python2
for i in range(1,13):
    for j in range(1,13):
        print('{:4}'.format(i*j), end="")
    print ("")
```

I guess your problem is that you're having a 5 alignment because you forgot that the `print foo,`
syntax in python 2 is adding a space. Also they say width of 4, whereas you tried to be smart, and
align accordingly to the size of the value.

edit: here's more details about what's wrong in your code, let's take two lines of your output:

```
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
10  20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100  110  120
AA␣BBB␣CCCC␣CCCC␣CCCC␣CCCC␣CCCC␣CCCC␣CCCC␣CCCC␣CCCC␣CCCC␣
```

so what your code is doing is:

```
if j==1: print i*j,
```

outputs the `AA␣`,

```
elif i>=10 and j==2:
    print '{0:3}'.format(i*j),
```

outputs the `BBB␣` and

```
else:
    print '{0:4}'.format(i*j),
```

outputs the `CCCC␣`.

The `␣` is an extra space added by python because of the use of the `,` at the end of the print, to get that, see that snippet:

```
>>> def foo():
...  print 1234,
...  print 1234,
...  print
... 
>>> foo()
1234 1234
```

The format `'{0:3}'` right aligns the integer to the right as expected, but only with a padding of three, whereas the `'{0:4}'` does it according to the rules. But as you're adding an extra space at the end, it's not working as you're writing it. That's why it's better to use python3's print expression that makes it simpler, using the `end` keyword.

Comment: Haha. They actually accepted this. Weird, since this solution has all those white spaces at the beginning of each line. Thanks!

Comment: it's not weird, it's by their requirement! *numbers are right-aligned* and *strip out leading/trailing spaces on each line* mean they don't want to have every number formatted on four columns with leading whitespaces. They just do not want to have more whitespaces before and after. I guess this is something they use for all code challenge and they did not notice it could get confusing for that particular one.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

> Print out the table in a matrix like fashion, each number formatted to a *width of 4* (The numbers are *right-aligned* and strip out leading/trailing spaces on each line).

However, the output fails to meet this requirement which is made more visible by timing bars.

```
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12^N
2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20   22   24^N
3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27   30   33   36^N
||||----||||----||||----||||----||||----||||----||||----
```

This correct padding for a "width of 4, right-aligned" should look like

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12^N
||||++++||||++++||||++++||||++++||||++++||||++++
```

And then with "strip out leading/trailing spaces on each line" the *correct* result is

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12^N
|++++||||++++||||++++||||++++||||++++||||++++
```

While the current *incorrect* output, with the timing bars for correct output looks like

```
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12^N
|++++||||++++||||++++||||++++||||++++||||++++???????????
```

Comment: Hm. Well, since I'm a newbie with Python (and programming in general), I'm not sure I understand how to right-align the output. Could you please help me out?

Comment: @cristianm's code is actually right aligning except for the `print i*j`

Comment: @zmo Yeah. You're right :| That's to honor the right-align requirement.

Comment: @zmo Nice observation. I've tried adding a '{0:0}'.format(i*j) but they still stay it's no good.

Comment: @cristianm Does it match the format above? I still suspect it's "too wide". See zmo's answer.

Comment: that's because you're formatting the output using no alignment, `{0:0}` is actually equivalent to `{}`. The first argument is to specificy the position in the `format()` argument list, and the second, after the `:` is for the padding. You need to use `"{:4}".format(i*j)`